# NTFS data recovery after being overwritten with Windows installer

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, data-recovery, ntfs, partition-recovery

I have two primary partitions on my hard disk. The first one contains local system drive (C) and is placed at the start of the disk. The second one is extended.
One day I got superblock of NTFS of the first drive damaged. I tried to fix it loading from the flash drive, running Ubuntu, but failed, as every utility asked to use `chkdsk`. The only way to run it was to make another partition in the end of the disk, install Windows 7 (The same image was installed on C) to a new partition (T) and running `chkdisk` from this OS.

The problem is that installer had a beginning of C partition overwritten with the bootloader, thus fixed. Every utility says it is OK and healthy now,  but I cannot access my old file system. I can only recover deleted files, but there is no use of them, as filenames and file hierarchy cannot be restored.

Is there any chance to recover file system with filenames and file hierarchy, as bootloader was overwritten with the same one and no other data was written to disk?

Comment: I just want to make sure that was there no partition labelled as `System Reserved` at the beginning of disk with the size of either `100Mb` or `350Mb`.

Comment: @BikuBalami Nope, but right now there is about ≈100mb of system data on C

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of `diskmgmt.msc` and upload it?

Comment: @BikuBalami The drive I was talking about is labeled as G here: https://image.ibb.co/gZEcY7/Untitled.png

Comment: Right Click to `My Computer` -> `Properties` -> `Advanced System Settings` -> `Settings...` (Startup and Recovery). In default operating system can you find second operating system as well? And what data that you are actually searching for? Is it files & folders or application data?

Comment: @BikuBalami No, there is the only instance of OS available. I want to recover Desktop folder and some game saves, OS itself and applications can be reinstalled without a problem.

Comment: Desktop files and folders can be recovered from `G:\Users\YourUserName\Desktop` as for game saves you can use third-party applications like ` https://www.easeus.com/backup-software/ to backup and restore after clean format. As for your previous OS, it seems like beyond recoverable. Sorry, could not be a great help but this is all I can suggest.

Comment: @BikuBalami I know where needed files are stored, the problem is I cannot access them. I can see MFT tables viewing the raw disk data, and I'm able to restore files without their names. Here is what software is able to see on disk: https://image.ibb.co/cPx9wS/Untitled3.png and here is one of MFT entries I found: https://image.ibb.co/nh5ZVn/Untitled2.png

Comment: `Right click` in G Drive -> `Properties` -> `Previous Version`. Do you see any old version of the shadow files before you changed the boot drive?

Comment: @BikuBalami no recovery points are presented, but I made one right before the problems started. I think I can try recovering it.

Comment: I can only wish you good luck.

Comment: @BikuBalami Finally got the data with cracked^W Active File Recovery tool. Thank you for help and patience!

Comment: You're welcome and congratulation for finally getting your data back.